# high-level regular expression with not

Tags: java, regex

Hi regular expression experts,

I have the following text

```
<[~UNKNOWN:a-z\.]> <[~UNKNOWN:A-Z\-0-9]> <[~UNKNOWN:A-Z\]a-z]
```

And the following reg expr

```
\[\~[^\[\~\]]*\]
```

It works fine for the 1st and 2nd group in the text but not for the 3rd one.

The 1st group is

```
[~UNKNOWN:a-z\.]
```

The 2nd is

```
[~UNKNOWN:A-Z\-0-9]
```

and the 3rd one is

```
[~UNKNOWN:A-Z\]a-z]
```

However the reg exp finds the following text

```
[~UNKNOWN:A-Z\]
```

I understand why and I know that I have to add the following rule to the reg exp:
starting with '[' and '~' characters and ending with ']' UNLESS there is a '\' in front of ']'. So I should add a NOT expression but not sure how.

Could anybody please help?

Thanks,
V.

Comment: Which programing language are you using?

Comment: Hi Pedro, I use Java.

Comment: **May help** https://regex101.com/r/Bywu1Y/2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work (first line pattern, second line your pattern (ignore whitespace), third line my changes):

```
\[\~(?:[^\[\~\]]|(?<=\\)\])*(?<!\\)\]
\[\~   [^\[\~\]]           *       \]
    (?:         |(?<=\\)\]) (?<!\\)
```

Your regex:

```
\[\~             # Literal characters [~
[^               # Character group, NONE of the following:
    \[\~\]       # [ or ~ or ]
]*               # 0 or more of this character group
\]               # Followed by ]
```

Your pattern in words:  `[~`, everything in between, up to the next `]`, as long as there is no `[` or `~` or `]` in there.

My pattern , only relevant changes explained:

```
\[\~             
(?:              # Non capturing group
    [^\[\~\]]    
    |            # OR
    (?<=\\)\]    # ], preceded by \
)*               
(?<!\\)\]         # ], not preceded by \
```

In words: Same as yours, plus `]` may be contained if it is preceded by `\`, and the closing `]` may not be preceded by `\`

Comment: Hi Pharaoh, thanks for the solution! I think it is what I need. One small thing is if I remove the trailing ']' character from '[~UNKNOWN:A-Z\]a-z]' then it will match the '[~UNKNOWN:A-Z\]' text which is not completely valid in my scenario. Can this be controlled somehow? Thanks!

Comment: I came up something like \[\~(?:[^\[\~\]]|(?<=\\)\])*(?<!\\)\] .It works but is it correct?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I would have done. I included that in my answer so that all backslashes can be copied, they are missing in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply:

```
<([^>]+)>?
```

---

[image]

---

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Bywu1Y/1)

Comment: This matches more than the original pattern, but it depends on possible input strings whether that's a problem. For example, this will match `abc` in `<abc>`. It will not match, however, `[~abc]`, which the original pattern does.

Comment: Thanks Pedro for the reply! Pharaoh is right, I need '[~' and ']' leading and trailing characters too.